# Edit/Read Mode & Disabled Styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, styling, multiline

Is there anyway for me to keep the style of multi line text box when it is disabled in edit mode, the same when viewed in read mode?

In screenshot 1, in edit mode, the boxes have scroll bars and adhere to my max height and all align.

In screenshot 2, in read mode, there are no boxes, it simply shows all values as text. I assume this is just the way xpages by default styles fields in read/edit mode? But I'd like to keep the boxes and scrollbars in read mode.

Thanks

Screenshot 1 (Edit mode - I want this styling in read mode also)
[image: Edit mode]

Screenshot 2 (Read mode)
[image: Read mode]

Comment: XP renders them differently in read/edit mode. You can write your own renderer for that component, to render them as multiline every time with "disabled" property for read mode. Google for "xpages renderer".

Answer (score 2):

Ignore my question, I somehow missed the `showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"` flag!

Leaving here incase anyone else misses the property too!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following CSS to create a scroll-able panel containing a repeat control but it can be used for individual fields.  Use a computed class for the style to disable it when in edit mode.

```
.FCHScroll  {
overflow-y:scroll;
max-height:100px;
border-color:rgb(128,128,128);
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin
}
```